# Selecting an Element | Javascript vs Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Whats the difference between an element selected by Javascript and the same element selected with jQuery?

I ran into this problem, trying to select a Html5 data attribute from an element with jQuery, the dataset would return undefined even though it was clearly set. Selecting the element with regular javascript works perfectly fine however.
So what behind the scenes is different that stops this example from working.

```js
var jsSelect = document.getElementById("jsSelect");
alert(jsSelect.dataset.name);

var jqSelect = $("#jsSelect");
alert(jqSelect.dataset.name);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="jsSelect" data-name="Javascript"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Whats the difference between an element selected by Javascript and the same element selected with jQuery?

There's no difference in the *element*, but jQuery gives you back the element wrapped in a jQuery object, whereas the DOM gives you a reference to the element itself. jQuery objects are *sets* of elements (since it lets you select more than one and treat them as a set).

To get the element itself from the jQuery object, you can index into it like an array:

```
var rawElement = jqSelect[0];
alert(rawElement.dataset.name);
```

```js
var jsSelect = document.getElementById("jsSelect");
snippet.log(jsSelect.dataset.name);

var jqSelect = $("#jsSelect");
var rawElement = jqSelect[0];
snippet.log(rawElement.dataset.name);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="jsSelect" data-name="Javascript"></div>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

To deal with `data-*` attributes, you can also use jQuery's [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) function:

```
alert(jqSelect.attr("data-name"));
```

```js
var jsSelect = document.getElementById("jsSelect");
snippet.log(jsSelect.dataset.name);

var jqSelect = $("#jsSelect");
snippet.log(jqSelect.attr("data-name"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="jsSelect" data-name="Javascript"></div>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

You *can* use jQuery's [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data) function, but it's important to read the documentation — `data` is **not** just a convenience wrapper for `dataset`. `data` manages a completely separate cache of data that is only **initialized** from `data-*` attributes (it doesn't update them).

```js
var jsSelect = document.getElementById("jsSelect");
snippet.log(jsSelect.dataset.name);

var jqSelect = $("#jsSelect");
snippet.log(jqSelect.data("name"));

// Note that `data` doesn't change the attribute:
jqSelect.data("name", "new name");
snippet.log("Attribute after changing with data: " +
            jqSelect.attr("data-name"));

// But you can retrieve the updated info via `data`
snippet.log("Data value after changing with data: " +
            jqSelect.data("name"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="jsSelect" data-name="Javascript"></div>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

You may be wondering why, if the jQuery object is a *set* of elements, you can use `attr` to get the `data-name` attribute from an element — which element does it get the attribute from? jQuery's accessor functions like `attr` are assymetrical: If you're *retrieving* information, they retrieve it from the first element in the set; if you're *setting* information (`jqSelect.attr("data-name", "newvalue")`), they set it on **all** of the elements in the set. Which sounds crazy, but works surprisingly well.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you for an amazing explaination!

Answer (score 3):

In case of jQuery `jqSelect` is a jQuery object so it doesn't have the `dataset` property, but you can use the [data api](http://api.jquery.com/data)

```js
var log = (function() {
  var $log = $('#log');
  return function(msg) {
    $('<p/>', {
      text: msg
    }).appendTo($log)
  }
})();

var jsSelect = document.getElementById("jsSelect");
log('native api:' + jsSelect.dataset.name);

var jqSelect = $("#jsSelect");
log('jquery api:' + jqSelect.data('name'));

var jqSelect = $("#jsSelect");
log('Using prop:' + jqSelect.prop('dataset').name);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="jsSelect" data-name="Javascript"></div>
<div id="log"></div>
```